# ReactJS: Unable to call parent function from nested child component

Tags: reactjs, components, setstate

I'm a very noobish coder, so I am sure this is something I am doing wrong.
I have App, ChildA and ChildB.
From ChildB throught ChildA, I am trying to call function in App named changeState().

In App have the function:

```
  changeState = (argument) => {
       console.log(argument)
  }
```

Then in the render part of App I do:

```
<childA changeState={this.changeState} />
```

Then in childA to receive it:

```
const childA = ({ changeState })
```

at this point I can call the function from childA, no problem. for example:

```
onClick={() => changeState('someVar from ChildA')}
```

But if pass it to ChildB, on component further down like so:

```
<ChildB changeState={changeState}/>
```

I am unable to call the changeState function from childB..

App is the main screen, child A is a menu and child B is a table in that menu with a button. I want that button to change state in the state of the main App.\

Many thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: do `<childA changeState={()=>changeState} />`

Comment: Hi Ashish, that did not work. I was even not able to call the function from childA that way which I am able to do when using `<childA changeState={this.changeState} />`

Comment: There's no reason why this shouldn't work. You will need to show the full code example for someone to find the mistake.